# Some function doesn't work when I set the parameter as a function in Class Syntax

Tags: javascript, class, syntax, parameters, prototype

I'm making a simple accordion-like menu using plain JS. The algorithm is:

1. When the users click one of `li` elements, add a class called `.open` to its sibling element called `list seq="two"` for expanding.
2. If the targeted element's sibling **hasn't** the class `.open`, remove the same other level's `.open` class first, then expands the sibling.

A problem is the `removeClass()` function doesn't work when I set the function as a parameter like this:

```
register(name, fx) {
    name.forEach(cur => {
        cur.addEventListener('click', (e) => fx(e));
    })
} // when I set the event register like this ...

...

removeClass(name, className) {
    name.forEach(cur => {
        cur.classList.remove(className);
    })
} // removeClass() function doesn't work
```

The weird thing that I can't understand is, the other functions are working fine such as toggling the `.open` class, or a static console function. Only this one, removeClass() doesn't work.

I'm going to use that `register()` in various ways so please don't answer me to remove the `fx` parameter unless this trick is officially illegal in JS.

I would like to know why this trick does't work in Class Syntax with an explanation and how to resolve this problem.

CodePen:

[Class Syntax w/o fx](https://codepen.io/sniffingdoggo/pen/BgJXje)

[Class Syntax w/ fx](https://codepen.io/sniffingdoggo/pen/xopvZX)

The Code (Class Syntax w/ fx):

```js
'use strict';
class Mobile {
    constructor(elem) {
        this.elem = document.querySelector(elem);
        this.list = this.elem.querySelectorAll('li[data="hasChild"]');
        this.listSecond = this.elem.querySelectorAll('ul[seq="two"]');
        this.register(this.list, this.deploy);
    }
    register(name, fx) {
        name.forEach(cur => {
            cur.addEventListener('click', (e) => fx(e));
        })
    }
    removeClass(name, className) {
        name.forEach(cur => {
            cur.classList.remove(className);
        })
    }
    // static removeClass(name, className) {
    //     name.forEach(cur => {
    //         cur.classList.remove(className);
    //     })
    // }
    static staticFx(param) {
        console.log(param);
    }
    deploy(e) {
        Mobile.staticFx('test'); // This works
        let sib = e.target.nextElementSibling,
            isSib = sib.classList.contains('open'),
            ternary = !isSib ? {
                remove: this.removeClass(this.listSecond, 'open'), // But this doesn't work
                // static: Mobile.removeClass(this.listSecond, 'open'), // Static fx also doesn't work 
                toggle: sib.classList.toggle('open') // even this one works
            } : null;
    }
}
const proMob = new Mobile('.panel');
```

```css
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      div, section {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        color: white;
        font-family: Helvetica;
      }
      a, a:active, a:visited, a:link {
          color: white;
          text-decoration: none;
      }
      ul, li {
          list-style-type: none;
      }
      li {
          padding: 1rem 0;
      }
      .panel {
          width: 600px;
          height: 600px;
          background-color: black;
      }
      .list {
          padding: 0 4rem;
      }
      .list[seq="two"] {
          max-height: 0;
          overflow: hidden;
          transition: max-height 400ms;
      }
      .open {
          max-height: 1000px !important;
      }
```

```html
      <div class="panel">
        <ul class="list" seq="one">
            <li data="hasChild">
                <a href="#">Category 1</a>
                <ul class="list" seq="two">
                    <li>Category 1-1</li>
                    <li>Category 1-2</li>
                    <li>Category 1-3</li>
                    <li>Category 1-4</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li data="hasChild">
                <a href="#">Category 2</a>
                <ul class="list" seq="two">
                    <li>Category 2-1</li>
                    <li>Category 2-2</li>
                    <li>Category 2-3</li>
                    <li>Category 2-4</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                Category 3
            </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

Comment: What is this unused local `ternary` variable, why are you creating an object literal there?

Comment: You are not calling the `deploy` method on the `Mobile` instance, `this` within the method body will be `undefined`. You'll want to bind the method to the current instance when passing it to `register(…)`.

Comment: @Bergi `ternary` is not an unused variable. I've created the object there for grouping up the results. You can check it out <a href="https://codepen.io/sniffingdoggo/pen/BgJXje">Here</a> the `ternary` works perfectly fine.

Comment: @Bergi Great advice. I've found the solution.

Comment: `ternary` is declared and initialised, but not used anywhere. You really should just write `if (!isSib) { this.removeClass(this.listSecond, 'open'); sib.classList.toggle('open'); }`.

Comment: @Bergi How did you check the `ternary` is not used anywhere in the code? Personally and for me, `ternary` style works fine and looks more better than if statement.

Comment: It simply doesn't appear more than once in the code that you posted, here or on the codepen you linked. I was assuming you posted the complete contents of your `destroy` method, of course. It doesn't use the object you're building anywhere.